# django 1.8.2 AttributeError: '_Meta' object has no attribute 'model_name'

Tags: django, migration

The project history started with django 1.3, current version 1.7.7.

Made migration to 1.8.2. Some warnings on 3d-party apps remained, but OK.

```
django-admin.py check - OK
```

BUT while trying any change just adding a new field to any model
`django-admin.py makemigrations`
returns

> AttributeError  '_Meta' object has no attribute 'model_name'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 125, in handle
    migration_name=self.migration_name,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 43, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 170, in _detect_changes
    old_field.rel.through._meta.model_name,
AttributeError: '_Meta' object has no attribute 'model_name'
```

As this is all around the core I can't understand where and what to look for.

Comment: Do any of your previous migrations have this attribute in them? (It might be worth making a copy of your migrations, deleting them all and rebaselining, if this is an option)

Comment: When I first has this error, I cleared migrations from all apps, and made migrate --fake.

Comment: Its going to be hard to tell where the problem is without a verifiable example (which I can imagine is hard to discover). What you can do is debug the makemigrations. In PyCharm, you can do this by just making a run configuration for makemigrations

Comment: Found! Looks like incompatibility of django-hstore field with 1.8. At least I know what to do. Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear! :) If you do find a solution, you may wish to add an answer to your own question to help anyone else that may come across this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sayse, classic debugging helped:

The reason was the nice django-hstore field was not ready to 1.8 yet..